# How would I make the first word of a string a mailto link to the last?

Tags: php, html, xhtml, mailto

I have a program that is reading in lines from a text file, and each line is formatted like this.

```
House 5682 Rose Road house@realtor.com
```

I want my program to print out each line where the word 'house' is a mailto link to the email, and the email is not printed. Right now I have it printing each line and cutting out the email, but I can't figure out how to do the mailto link. I need it to come out like this:

```
House 5682 Rose Road
```

With 'House' mailto linked to house@realtor.com. This is what I have so far.

```
$houses = file('houseList.txt');
$houseNumber = 1;
foreach($houses as $house)
{
  $line = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $house);
  echo " ".$houseNumber." ";
  echo substr($line,0,strrpos($house, ' '))."\n";
  $houseNumber++;
}
```

Comment: you want to make the first word to mailto or only house?

Comment: I want the first word to be house, but have it be a link to mailto the email at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it. the whole line, minus the email address, is the link. easy to modify if you just want house to be the anchor.

```
$houses = file('houseList.txt');
$houseNumber = 1;
foreach($houses as $house)
{
  $pos    = strrpos($house," ");
  $mailto = substr($house, $pos+1);
  $house  = substr($house, 0, $pos);

  echo "<a href=mailto:$mailto>$house</a><br>";
  $houseNumber++;
}
```

Comment: This did add the mailto link to the first word like it was supposed to, but now the rest of the line is not showing up? The part that has the address.

Comment: here is my output: <a href=mailto:house@realtor.com>House 5682 Rose Road</a>